# Align two sections titles

Tags: graphics, sectioning, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have recently started learning latex, and i have the following latex code with two minipages, and two sections in the first section i added two images, then i added an other minipage and a section within it, but i don't know why i am not able to align the second section title with that of the first section, i tried with hspace with no success:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
\title{Imagenes, Tablas y Ecuaciones}
\date{}
\maketitle
\section{Imagenes}
\begin{minipage}[t]{4.8in}
\subsection{Super mario}
\begin{wrapfigure}{}{0.3\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=0\linewidth,height=5cm]{mario.png} 
 \caption {Super mario} 
\label{mario}
\end{wrapfigure}
 \flushright \vspace{-0.7in} \hspace{2cm} \subsection{Tux}
\begin{wrapfigure}{H}{9in}
 \vspace{-7.5cm} \hspace{10cm} \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{tux.png} 
 \hspace{4cm} \caption {Tux} 
\label{mario}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{8in}
\vspace{2cm}   \section{Tabla}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

and here is the result i am getting now:
[image]

is there anyway to align **1.Imagenes**  with **2.Tabla** without affecting the images placement ?

Comment: Did you try beginning the first minipage *before* section 1. Imagenes?

Comment: Don't use `\flushright`; the correct command is `\raggedleft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put  the first `\begin{minipage}` just *before* `\section{Imagenes}`.